# Word transformation function

Tags: python, pig-latin

My code does what it's suppose to do but the code is failing Pylint checks.
After pasting my code into Pylint checker, it says that *Too many branches (15/12)* and its failed me on the Pylint checks.

How can this be cleaned up?

```
"""Docstring"""
import words

def nicer_englishify_word(word):
    """Docstring"""
    wordx = word.lower()
    wordy = ""
    if wordx.endswith('moo'):
        vowel = True
    else:
        vowel = False
    if vowel == True:
        wordy1 = wordx[-3] + wordx[:-3]
        wordy2 = wordx[:-3]
        if wordy1 in words.get_word_list():
            wordy11 = True
        else:
            wordy11 = False
        if wordy2 in words.get_word_list():
            wordy22 = True
        else:
            wordy22 = False
        if wordy11 == wordy22:
            if wordy11 == True:
                wordy = "sametrue"
            else:
                wordy = "samefalse"
        else:
            if wordy22 == False:
                wordy = "[" + wordx[-3] + wordx[:-3] + "]"    
            else:
                wordy = "[" + wordx[:-3] + "]"
        if wordy == "sametrue":
            wordy = wordx[-3] + wordx[:-3] + " or " + wordx[:-3]
            wordy = "<" + wordy + ">"
        if wordy == "samefalse":
            wordy = wordx[-3] + wordx[:-3] + " or " + wordx[:-3]
            wordy = "(" + wordy + ")"
    else:
        wordy = wordx[-3] + wordx[:-3]
    return wordy


def nicer_englishify_sentence(sentence):
    """docstring"""
    stringlist = sentence.split()
    result = "" 
    for item in stringlist:
        result = result + nicer_englishify_word(item) + " " 
    result = result[:-1]
    return result
```

Comment: Well, pylint doesn't like that you're using so many `if`s ans `else`s. That doesn't mean your code is wrong. pylint doesn't check for correctness.

Comment: Why don't you use `elif` statements ?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please add some description of what the intended purpose of your code is. (See [ask].)

Answer (score 6):

#### If true, true. If false, false.

Your code is filled with situations like this:

```
if someCondition:
    variable = True
else:
    variable = False
```

You can replace all those occurrences with a simple assignment:

```
variable = someCondition
```

#### If, and if not

Additionally, there's no need to add `== True` in a comparison. The Python way of `x == False` is to do `not x`

#### Conditional ternary operator

```
if wordy11:
    wordy = "sametrue"
else:
    wordy = "samefalse"
```

Can be written as:

```
wordy = "sametrue" if wordy11 else "samefalse"
```

#### Variable names

What on earth is `wordy`? What type is it? It seems to be one variable used for all kinds of things. I'd recommend making these separate variables and using more descriptive variable names.

#### Result

This will clean up your code a bit at least, to this point:

```
"""Docstring"""
import words


def nicer_englishify_word(word):
    """Docstring"""
    wordx = word.lower()
    wordy = ""

    if wordx.endswith('moo'):
        wordy1 = wordx[-3] + wordx[:-3]
        wordy2 = wordx[:-3]
        wordy11 = wordy1 in words.get_word_list()
        wordy22 = wordy2 in words.get_word_list()
        if wordy11 == wordy22:
            wordy = "sametrue" if wordy11 else "samefalse"
        else:
            if not wordy22:
                wordy = "[" + wordx[-3] + wordx[:-3] + "]"    
            else:
                wordy = "[" + wordx[:-3] + "]"
        wordy = wordx[-3] + wordx[:-3] + " or " + wordx[:-3]
        wordy = "<" + wordy + ">" if wordy == "sametrue" else "(" + wordy + ")"
    else:
        wordy = wordx[-3] + wordx[:-3]
    return wordy
```

Comment: @Kevin Those are mostly probably better as ternary expressions anyway, like `wordy = "sametrue" if wordy11 else "samefalse"`, or better yet `wordy = "same" + str(wordy11).lower()`

Comment: @TheBlackCat Done. I'm not using Python very often but I think what I made it should be correct. (there is one more place that technically can be changed to a ternary, I know)

Comment: You might need to use `variable = bool(someCondition)` if `someCondition` wasn't boolean to begin with.

Comment: You took out the explaining variable `vowel`, which was the closest thing that the code had to some kind of documentation!

Comment: @200_success Okay, true. Although that could easily be added again. I don't see the connection between `vowel` and `wordx.endswith('moo')` though, so perhaps it's more confusion than documentation?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Simon's changes, here are some more improvements:

1. You recalculate `wordy1` and `wordy2` a lot.  You should define them once and re-use them whenever you need.
2. `wordy1` uses `wordy2`.  So you can define `wordy1` in terms of `wordy2`.
3. You can use something like `'[{}]'.format(foo)` instead of something like `'[' + foo + ']'` to make your code clearer (in my opinion).
4. If you use `format`, you don't have to do so immediately.  So you can define your words, and define your separators, then combine them later.
5. You can short-circuit your last `else` clause by putting it near the beginning and having it `return` the result.  This allows you to unindent a large block of code.
6. You never use the initial `wordy` you create.  Get rid of it
7. You re-use variable names for different things.  That is confusing.  You should use more descriptive names (I have taken a shot at that in my example below).
8. If `get_word_list` is expensive, you should probably only do it once and store it as a global variable.  You can then pass it as a default argument to speed up access.  This also makes the code more flexible since you can specify an alternative word list if you want.
9. You should use boolean operations rather than `==` to check if multiple booleans are the same.  In this case, you can reverse your `if` test and use `xor`, which will will return `True` if and only if exactly one is `True`.  Python doesn't explicitly have `xor`.  Since you are sure in this case that both are `bool`, you can use `^` instead.
10. `'sametrue'` and `'samefalse'` are just used as test values later.  You can remove these by moving the test into the code block where you originally create them.

So here is a somewhat simplified version:

```
"""Docstring"""
import words

WORD_LIST = words.get_word_list()


def nicer_englishify_word(word, word_list=WORD_LIST):
    """Docstring"""
    word = word.lower()

    word2 = word[:-3]
    word1 = word[-3] + word2

    if not word.endswith('moo'):
        return word1

    word1isin = word1 in word_list
    word2isin = word2 in word_list
    if word1isin ^ word2isin:
        inner = word2 if word2isin else word1
        outer = "[{}]"
    else:
        inner = "{} or {}".format(word2, word1)
        outer = "<{}>" if word1isin else "({})"
    return outer.format(inner)
```

Answer (score 1):

### 3 the perfect number

The number `3` is repeated 11 times in your code. What does that `3` stand for? Your code is kind of mysterious: I can't decide, but I am sure you can. Define a constant:

```
MEANINGFUL_NAME = 3
```

Comment: Everywhere it is used is as part of a slice, and there are only two such slices that are re-done over and over.  It would be easier to just do each slice once, put each in a variable, and then use those variables.